# DRF - JWT How to fix Token still active after expired?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using Djangorestframework with djangorestframework-simplejwt library, the token system is working except that after an access and refresh token are both expired ( I can confirm with postman ) the frontent app (Vue & axios) is able to still GET the updated data, how is this possible? When i check the axios request the token is the same as the one I use in postman, in Postman it gives me "Token Invalid or expired" but in axios it receives all the data and 200 OK.

These are the configs:

```
settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=24),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
}
```

```
urls.py

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView
from dgmon.views import MyTokenObtainPairView
app_name = 'dgmon'

admin.site.site_header = settings.ADMIN_SITE_HEADER
admin.site.site_title = settings.ADMIN_SITE_TITLE

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include('dgmon.urls')),
    path('api/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),

]
```

```
views.py

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from dgmon.serializers import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

```
serializers.py

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        data['user'] = self.user.username
        data['groups'] = self.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
        return data
```

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint _requires_ authentication?  If you're in chrome, open a new incognito went with `ctrl`+`shift`+`i` and then navigate to that endpoint. Does it still work with _no_ authentication?  If so, that endpoint may have read only access.  Is `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` set to `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` in your settings.py file?

Comment: Thanks, I missed the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in settings.py